# How to find a `span` element inside of the second div element in CSS if that `span` inside of an anchor?

Tags: css, kendo-window

I'm building a Kendo.Window() that generates html when page is rendered.

This is a part that I would like to get some help on to set a color for a `span` element:

[image]

Here, I need to set a color for `k-icon` that is inside of an anchor `a`, which is inside of a `div` with a class of `customTitle`

How can I accomplish something like that with `css`?

Comment: `div.customTitle a .k-icon {}` ?

Comment: Thank you very much. It was fast.